# Using $state inside $httpinterceptor working but i have fail compile (AngularJS + TypeScript)

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i have a problem with my httpinterceptor in angularJS and typescript.
I use ui.router and i redirect in to my login page when error 401.

It's working but i have error in my console : 'angular.min.js:497 Error: [$compile:tpload] '.

Why i have this error ?

There is my code:

```
module Security {

export class AuthentificationInterceptor {

    private static instance: AuthentificationInterceptor;

    constructor(private $q: ng.IQService, private $injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService) { }

    public static Factory($q: ng.IQService, $injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService) {
        AuthentificationInterceptor.instance = new AuthentificationInterceptor($q, $injector);

        return AuthentificationInterceptor.instance;
    }

    public response = (response):ng.IHttpPromise<any> => {
        var vm = Security.AuthentificationInterceptor.instance;

        console.log(response);
        return response || vm.$q.when(response);
    }
    public responseError = (error):ng.IHttpPromise<any> => {
        var vm = Security.AuthentificationInterceptor.instance;
        console.log(error);

        if (error.status === 401) {
            let $state: ng.ui.IStateService;

            $state = vm.$injector.get('$state') as ng.ui.IStateService;
            $state.go('login');
        };

        return vm.$q.reject(error);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think your error is in the interceptor.
Are you sure your login page works correctly ? Seems to me that angular fails to load a template (login template ?)
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload

Comment: I work with ASP MVC. My page login is a test i have just <h1>Login</h1>
in a partial view. That's strange.

Comment: The template itself isn't the issue. The problem is that angular can't find it (a 404 not found should be logged in the network tab of your browser dev tools)

Comment: Yes my page Test where i put my filter Authorize not found because the filter prevent access. After my page login working. The error is in PartialViewResult Test(). The breackpoint is never rechead.